# ASP.NET Core Identity post request doesn't get called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I've ran into a problem with registering users using ASP.NET Identity in my ASP.NET Core project.

I've made things simpler by just changing the ViewData["Iets"] for now, just to check if it works, but no..

**My controller:**

```
public /*async Task<IActionResult>*/ IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model, string ReturnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["Iets"] = "Gelukt!";
            return View();

            //ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = ReturnUrl;

            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
            //    var user = new ApplicationUser { Email = model.Email };
            //    var result = await _UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            //    if (result.Succeeded)
            //    {
            //        await _SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            //        _Logger.LogInformation(3, "User: {0}, has created a new account.", model.Email);

            //        return RedirectToLocal(ReturnUrl);
            //    }

            //    AddErrors(result);
            //}

            //// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            //return View(model);
        }
```

**And my view:**

```
@model Project_Dojo.Models.AccountViewModels.RegisterViewModel

@ViewData["Iets"]

<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

One thing I noticed is that my tags like `asp-controller` turn up in red color instead of purple as I have seen in other views.

So what happens when I press the button is that it just goes to `localhost/Account/Register` and returns a blank page instead of my layout page with the `ViewData` on it.

I hope someone has a solution for this problem.

Comment: I think you'll need to add some additional information. Did you add the right port? I see you didn't specify the port in the url. Perhaps access is denied (check the statuscode) or there are issues with the routing. Can you show the declaration of the controller (including attributes) and from startup the configuration of the routing? Can you reach other controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the HtmlHelpers in my _ViewImports.cshtml, that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `[HttpPost]` as attribute to the action.

Comment: @Peurr have you tried to add `RouteAttribute` to your action ?

Answer (score 0):

> One thing I noticed is that my tags like asp-controller turn up in red color instead of purple as I have seen in other views.

Is your view called `Register.cshtml`?  If it isn't, if it's something like `Register.html` then it wont behave as an MVC view.  Maybe try correcting the file extension if it isn't `cshtml`.